# API response should not get again in Fragment1 when returning from second Fragment2

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm calling web service in onCreateView() method and get response and display data in Fragment1. Now i click on any item from response and move to Fragment2. Now I'm returning to Fragment1, webservice is call again because Fragment1's onCreateView() method called again. But i want to avoid this web service call again. Please help me to avoid this problem.

Comment: try to hit the webservice in  onCreate() method. if you call the fragment1 from backstack, onCreateView() will be called. and service will not hit again. If you have any problem, Please reply.

Comment: @Vivek, I'm just using popBackStack method fro returning to Fragment1. Should this work?

Comment: if you added fragment1 to backstack before going to fragment2. Yes it should work. Try that.

Comment: @Vivek, I get rid of this problem. Thanx

Comment: Ok. Enjoy. Please upvote my comment if you liked this. Thanks.

Comment: @vivek make it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to hit the webservice in onCreate() method, if you added fragment1 to backstack before going to fragment2. When you Pop the fragment1 from backstack onCreateView() will be called not oncreate().